# No rule to make target when building drivers for SIM7600A

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, pi, wwan, hat

Attempting to install the drivers for a Waveshare SIM 7600A-h HAT to provide WWAN access to a Raspberry Pi 4.

Using manufacturer driver software provided from https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM7600A-H_4G_HAT. Followed instructions from included PDF to install GobiSerial driver.

The initial error when trying make was:

```
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.10.17-v7l+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2[/code]
```

After some research I updated the headers and retried, getting this:

```
 make
rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions Module.* modules.order
make -C /lib/modules/5.10.17-v7l+/build M=/home/pi/Desktop/SIM7X00-Driver/Linux driver/gobiserial modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.17-v7l+'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'driver/gobiserial'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.17-v7l+'
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add references to the source of the software and the instructions you followed.

Comment: I've updated...so now what?

Comment: Then please clarify **in the question**: Did you follow the instructions in "kernel-deploy-guide"? (I found this guide by telepathy, no need to learn how to navigate a website.) If not, tell us where to find other instructions.